# startActivityForResult: finish() returning to wrong activity

Tags: java, android

So I have 3 activities: MainActivity, AddEntryActivity, and CategoryActivity. I want to use startActivityForResult from Main -> AddEntry, and then AddEntry -> Category and have the data from Category passed back to AddEntry where it's used as a field in the Entry object result I'm sending back to Main. The problem is, when I call finish() in AddEntryActivity (after returning from CategoryActivity), CategoryActivity opens again. I think it may be a problem with the intents/contexts but I'm new to android dev so I can't figure out what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated!

I am currently calling startActivityForResult() from MainActivity (on button press) to get to AddEntry.

```
case R.id.addEntryButton: 
            Intent in = new Intent(this, AddEntryActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(in, 111);
            break;
```

Then from AddEntryActivity, I call another startActivityForResult to get to CategoryActivity (on button press again).

```
case R.id.chooseCategory:
            Intent catAct = new Intent(this, CategoryActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(catAct, 222);
            break;
```

From CategoryActivity, the user can choose a category and it's sent back to AddEntryActivity (I've checked that this works).

In CategoryActivity:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String category = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    i.putExtra("Category", category);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
    finish();
}
```

In AddEntryActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 222 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String cat = data.getStringExtra("Category");
        category.setText(cat);
        categoryString = cat;
    }
}
```

Then, in AddEntryActivity, when the confirm button is pressed I want to return to MainActivity with a new Entry object containing the category field that was returned from CategoryActivity. So I have this:

```
case R.id.confirmEntryButton:

            Entry entry = new Entry(descString, amountString, date.getText().toString(), categoryString);

            Intent main = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            main.putExtra("newEntry", entry);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, main);
            finish();
```

The problem is, when the confirm button is pressed, the CategoryActivity screen pops up again. The weird thing is, the onActivityResult method in MainActivity (below) actually runs as when you close the CategoryActivity screen via the back button, you can see that the entry object has been added so I can't seem to figure out what's causing the category screen to pop up.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 111 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Entry entry = data.getParcelableExtra("newEntry");
        entries.add(entry);

        entryListView.setAdapter(eAdapter);

    }
}
```

Comment: Try using `Intent main = new Intent()` in your `confirmEntryButton` routine (rather than `Intent(this, MainActivity.class)`). Also check that you have `break` statements for all cases in the switch case (it's not shown in the `confirmEntryButton` code you posted), but that might just be a copy paste error. If it's not there it could be falling through to the `chooseCategory` case too.

Comment: @TylerV thank you so much! The break statement fixed it :)

Comment: Great! I've added it as an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Check your switch case statement to make sure it isn't missing a break and falling through to the next part.